# Is it possible to provide access only to collaborators in github

Tags: github

I am creating a public repository to create resource library. As it is initial phase of the project I want to create certain issues that only the collaborators have full access. Is it possible? If not what is the way that will serve the purpose?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, it has

you can Invite collaborators for working in your repo, also you can give different access permission for everyone.

its clearly explained over [here](https://help.github.com/articles/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository/)

Comment: May be you misunderstood my question. I want to grant access "only" to collaborators and hide it from the rest of the world and that also in a public repository.